# csv file encoding issue in ruby

Tags: ruby, csv

I parsing a csv file using ruby and getting an error

```
invalid byte sequence in utf-8 csv
```

I tried with encoding option

```
    CSV.foreach(path, {headers: true, encoding: 'windows-1251:utf-8'}) do |row|
        new_row = {}
        headers = []
        row.each do |k,v|
            headers << k
            v = v.force_encoding('UTF-8') || ''
            v.gsub! "\xE2\x80\x96", "-"
            v.gsub! "\xE2\x80\x93", "-"
            v.gsub! "\xE2\x80\x94", "-"
            v.gsub! "\xE2\x80\x95", "-"
            v.gsub! "\xE2\x80\x98", "'"
            v.gsub! "\xE2\x80\x99", "'"
            v.gsub! "\xE2\x80\x9C", "\""
            v.gsub! "\xE2\x80\x9D", "\""
            v.gsub! "\xE2\x80\xA6", "..."
            v.gsub! "\x0D\x0A", "\n"
            v.gsub! "\xC2\xA0", " "
            v.gsub! "\xC2\xB0", " "

            new_row[k] = v
        end

        output_csv.puts headers if output_csv.header_row?
        output_csv.puts new_row
    end
```

now i'm ended up with

```
incompatible encoding regexp match (ASCII-8BIT regexp with UTF-8 string)
```

The string which is raising this issue in CSV file is "G�ran"

Below is the sample input row

```
David Evans & Assocs    www.deainc.com  13858534    jpv@deainc.com  G�ran   Volk    5034990383
```

Can anyone suggest me how to solve this issue.

Comment: edited my question with a sample input row

Comment: You have a scraped symbols in your input already. Why would you expect them to be fixed automagically?

Comment: the file which I have got is in that way. what can i do now?

Comment: Most likely you can do nothing. Would you mind to publish your file not via copy-paste but as a normal file somewhere on dropbox-like service? I could take a look at.

Comment: I will try to share with you. But what is this character after G,  'G�ran'?

Comment: Atleast may i know why this issue is coming as I dont really understand this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That issue most likely induced by *saving* the file in wrong encoding. Say, you have unicode symbol “★” in your file. Saving it as `ASCII` or `Latin1` or other 1-byte-per-symbol encoding, you *loose some data*.

The symbol “�” is known as [replacement character](http://unicode-table.com/en/search/?q=%EF%BF%BD). It’s used to indicate “here was unicode that was apparently lost during encoding convertion.”